# Remove multiple lines where string occurs and concatenate

Tags: bash, perl

I'm new to Bash/Perl and trying to remove multiple lines in a text file where a string occurs. To remove a single line so far I have:

```
perl -ne '/somestring/ or print' /usr/file.txt > /usr/file1.tmp
```

To replace a second line I use:

```
perl -ne '/anotherstring/ or print' /usr/file.txt > /usr/file2.tmp
```

How can I concatenate file and file2.tmp?

Or how can I modify the command to remove multiple lines where `somestring` and `anotherstring` occur?

Comment: `perl -ne '/somestring|anotherstring/ or print' /usr/file.txt > /usr/file2.tmp` but `grep -v` is more suitable here.

Comment: or `egrep -v` if you're using a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks but `grep -v  'somestring' /usr/file.txt` works` but `grep -v 'somestring|anotherstring'  /usr/file.txt` returns no result which is why I use Perl.

Comment: That's because `grep` by default uses POSIX BRE (basic regex), where you have to escape `|`, like this: `grep 'somestring\|anotherstring' ...`. The alternative is to use extended regex (ERE), enabled with `-E` flag, or (as suggested by Chris), `egrep`. For example: `grep -E 'somestring|anotherstring' ..`.

Comment: @randomir escaping the `|` does not work for me, also `-E` switch is an illegal option, I'm using an old version of grep.

Comment: Which platform/grep version are you on?

Comment: @randomir I'm using Solaris. I found egrep in `/usr/bin/egrep` so your `-E` solution now works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I concatenate file and file2.tmp?

That could be done with

```
cat file file2.tmp >> file3.tmp
```

Or if by `file` you mean `file1.tmp`,

```
cat file1.tmp file2.tmp >> file3.tmp
```

---

However, that is different from what you're describing in the rest of your question (i.e. removing any line where any of two patterns appears). That could be done by chaining your commands:

```
perl -ne '/somestring/ or print' /usr/file.txt > /usr/file1.tmp
perl -ne '/anotherstring/ or print' /usr/file1.tmp > /usr/file2.tmp
```

You can use a pipe to get rid of the intermediate file `file1.tmp`:

```
perl -ne '/somestring/ or print' /usr/file.txt | perl -ne '/anotherstring/ or print' > /usr/file2.tmp
```

This can also be done by using `grep` (assuming your strings don't make use of any Perl-specific regex features):

```
grep -v somestring /usr/file.txt | grep -v anotherstring > /usr/file2.tmp
```

Finally, you can combine the filtering into one command/regex:

```
perl -ne '/somestring|anotherstring/ or print' /usr/file.txt > /usr/file2.tmp
```

Or using `grep`:

```
grep -v 'somestring\|anotherstring' /usr/file.txt > /usr/file2.tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

I had some fun with your program, and wrote a highly dynamic Perl program
to print the matches or non-matches for words in each line of any user defined file, and then right the requested lines which match or do not match the file to the screen and to a new user-defined outfile.

We will be parsing this file: iris_dataset.csv:

```
"Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species"
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,"setosa"
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,"setosa"
4.8,3,1.4,0.3,"setosa"
5.1,3.8,1.6,0.2,"setosa"
4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,"setosa"
7,3.2,4.7,1.4,"versicolor"
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,"versicolor"
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,"versicolor"
6.6,3,4.4,1.4,"versicolor"
5.5,2.4,3.7,1,"versicolor"
6.3,3.3,6,2.5,"virginica"
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,"virginica"
7.1,3,5.9,2.1,"virginica"
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,"virginica"
5.9,3,5.1,1.8,"virginica"
```

It's a comma separated value file with columns separated by commas.
You could see each column of items more nicely if you were looking at this file in a spreadsheet. What we will be looking for is Species of the file, so the possible items to match are "setosa", "versicolor", and "virginica".

My program first asks for the file that you want to read from..
In this case, it's iris_dataset.csv, though it could be any file. Then you write the name of a file that you would want to write to. I call it new_iris.csv, but you can call it anything.

Then we tell the program how many items we are looking for, so if there's 3 items I can type: setosa, versicolor, virginica in any order. If there are two I can type only two items, and if there is one, then I can only type only setosa or versicolor or virginica in this example file.

Then we are asked if we want to KEEP the lines which match our items,
or if we want to REMOVE the lines of the file which match our files. If we keep the matches, we get the lines which match those items printed to the screen and to our outfile. If we select remove, we get the lines which do not match those items printed to the screen and to our file. If we select neither KEEP nor REMOVE, then we get an error message and our new empty outfile is deleted since it contains nothing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Program: perl_matching.pl
use strict; # Means that we have to explicitly declare our variables with "my", "our" or "local" as we want their scope defined. 
use warnings; # We want to know if and if where errors are showing up in our program. 
use feature 'say'; # Like print, but with automatic ending newline.
use feature 'switch'; # Perl given:when switch statement. 
no warnings 'experimental'; # Perl has something against switch. 

########### This block of code right here is basically equivalent to a unit ls command ##############
opendir(DIR, "."); # Opens the current working directory 
my @files = readdir(DIR); # Reads all files in the current working directory into an array @files. 
closedir(DIR); # Now that we have the array of files, we can close our current working directory.
say "Here are the list of files in your current working directory";
foreach(@files){print "$_\t";} # $_ is the default variable for each item in an array.
########### It is not critical to run the program ####################  

say "\nGive me your filename to read from, extensions and all ..."; # It would be a good idea to have your filename in yoru working directory.
chomp(my $file_read = <STDIN>); # This makes the filename dynamic from user input. 
say "Give me your filename to write to, extensions and all ...";
chomp(my $file_write = <STDIN>); # results will be printed to this file, and standard output. # chomp removes newlines from standard input.

# ' < ' to read from, and '>', to write to ... 
# Opening your file to read from: 
open(my $filehandle_read, '<', $file_read) or die "Problem reading file $_ because $!";
# Open your file to write to. 
open(my $filehandle_write, '>', $file_write) or die "Problem reading file $_ because $!";

say "How many matches are you going to give me?";
my $match_num = <STDIN>;
say "Okay give me the matches now, pressing Enter key between each match.";

my $i = 1; # This is our incrementer between matches. 
my $matches; # This is each match presented line by line. 
my @match_list; # This is our array (list) of $matches
while($i <= $match_num)
{
    $matches = <STDIN>; # One match at a time from standard input. 
    push @match_list, $matches; # Pushes all individual $matches into a list @match_list
    $i = $i + 1; # Increase the incrementor by one so this loop don't last forever. 
}
chomp(@match_list);

undef($matches); # I am clearing each match, so that I can redefine this variable. 

$matches = join('|', @match_list); # " | " is part of a regular expression which means "or" for each item in this scalar matches. 
say "This is what your redefined matches variable looks like: $matches"; 

say "Now you get a choice for your matches"; 
say "KEEP or REMOVE?"; # if you type Keep (case insensitive) you print only the matches to the new file. If you type Remove (case insensitive) you print only the lines to the newfile which do not contain the matches.  
chomp(my $choice = <STDIN>);

my @lines_all = <$filehandle_read>; # The filehandle contains everything in the file, so we can pull all lines of the file to read into an array, where each item in the array is each line of the file opened for reading. 
close $filehandle_read; # we can now close the filehandle for the file for reading since we just pulled all the information from it. 
# We grep for the matching " =~ " lines of our file to read. 
my @lines_matching = grep{$_ =~ m/$matches/} @lines_all;
# We grep for the non-matching " !~ " lines of our file to read.
# Note: $_ is a default variable for every item in the array.   
my @lines_not_matching = grep{$_ !~ m/$matches/} @lines_all;


# This is a Perl style switch statement.
# Note: A given::when::when::default switch statement. 
# is basically equivalent to ...
# while::if::elsif::else statement. 

# In this switch statement only one choice is performed,
# which one depends on if you said "Keep" or "Remove" in your choice. 
given($choice)
{
    when($choice =~ m/Keep/i) # "i" is for case-insensitive, so Keep, KEEP, kEeP, etc are valid. 
    {
    say @lines_matching; # Print the matching lines to the screen. 
    print $filehandle_write @lines_matching; # Print the matching lines to the file. 
    close $filehandle_write; # Close the file now that we are done with it. 
    }
    when($choice =~ m/Remove/i) 
    {
    say @lines_not_matching; # Print the lines that match to the screen.
    print $filehandle_write @lines_not_matching; # Print the lines that do not match to the screen. 
    close $filehandle_write; # Close the file now that we are done with it.
    }
    default 
    {
    say "You must have selected a choice other than Keep or Remove. Don't do that!";
    close $filehandle_write; # Close the file now that we are done with it. 
    unlink($file_write) or warn "Could not unlink file $file_write"; # If you selected neither keep nor remove, we delete the new file to write to as it contains nothing.  
    }
}
```

Here is the script in action:

I ask to Remove the lines which contain versicolor and setosa, so only the lines which contain virginica will be printed to the screen and to my outfile which I called new_iris.csv. Again, I asked for 2 items. Note: As in my program, you can type the words Keep or Remove in any case insensitive manner.

```
  >perl perl_matching.pl
   Here are the list of files in your current working directory
.       ..      iris_dataset.csv        perl_matching.pl
Give me your filename to read from, extensions and all ...
iris_dataset.csv
Give me your filename to write to, extensions and all ...
new_iris.csv
How many matches are you going to give me?
2
Okay give me the matches now, pressing Enter key between each match.
setosa
versicolor
This is what your redefined matches variable looks like: setosa|versicolor
Now you get a choice for your matches
KEEP or REMOVE?
Remove
"Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species"
6.3,3.3,6,2.5,"virginica"
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,"virginica"
7.1,3,5.9,2.1,"virginica"
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,"virginica"
5.9,3,5.1,1.8,"virginica"
```

So only those lines which do not contain the words setosa and versicolor are printed to our file: new_iris.csv:

```
"Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species"
6.3,3.3,6,2.5,"virginica"
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,"virginica"
7.1,3,5.9,2.1,"virginica"
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,"virginica"
5.9,3,5.1,1.8,"virginica"
```

I completely enjoy playing with standard input in Perl.
You can use my script to only print the lines of the file which contain 
setosa. (You only ask for 1 match.)

Comment: What is wrong with my code? It is dynamic. No variables are defined outside of their scope. I used every variable. I commented every function of my program. My program does exactly what it says it would do. Do you just not like the amount of lines of my code? I'm sure you have written longer programs with less comments.

Comment: "*It is dynamic*" is meaningless. `$matches` is arguably defined outside of its scope. `undef $matches` is bad style. Why are you doing that in the first place, if you're just going to overwrite it in the next line? Why use the same variable for two completely different things?

Comment: Don't use bareword filehandles (or directory handles, in this case).

Comment: `given`/`when` throws warnings for a reason. Don't use it in new code; don't just silence the warnings.

Comment: The error message for `$file_write` says there's a problem with reading the file.

Comment: Why did I undefine $matches? So that instead of containing either  versicolor or setosa, it now contains $matches = 'versicolor|setosa' which is a scalar variable with a | which makes every item useful in a regular expression where '|' defines or.

Comment: The error message for `unlink` doesn't include `$!`.

Comment: Parsing CSV with regexes is a bad idea in general (as is reading a CSV file line by line; CSV fields can contain line breaks).

Comment: That's what no warnings experimental does. It silences warnings for the switch statement that perl automatically gives even when there is nothing wrong with your switch statement.

Comment: `$i = $i + 1` is highly unidiomatic. `$i++` would be better, but then the whole counting `while` loop is better written using `foreach`.

Comment: Parsing CSV with regular expressions may normally be a bad idea in general, but I'm not searching for commas, so there is no problem here.

Comment: There's no point in explicitly closing (some of) your file handles if you don't check for errors.

Comment: $i++ is highly idiomatic, but I think $i = $i + 1 makes more sense to new programmers. It did to me. I know what they both mean now.

Comment: So will you be happy if I add more or die messages to files I close and to the directory that I opened and closed?

Comment: Your comment re: `undef $matches` makes no sense. `undef $matches` doesn't set `$matches = 'versicolor|setosa'`; `$matches = join('|', ...)` does that. So why use `undef $matches`?

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I cleared the variable before I did that. That was the message that I was trying to convey. Are you saying that that was unnecessary? Perhaps it was.

Comment: "*That's what no warnings experimental does. It silences warnings ...*" - yes, and I said not to do that. Besides, your `given`/`when` logic would actually be clearer if it were written as an `if`/`elsif` chain.

Comment: You're not searching for commas; you've written a generic search program and you let the user enter the search string(s). At minimum your chosen example is suboptimal.

Comment: So you want me to have the program search for commas?

Comment: I don't think you could write this code in a way that would make me completely happy because what it does is in itself weird. The program doesn't take any command line arguments and forces the user to enter everything interactively (which is annoying and means you can't reuse the program in other scripts), but doesn't provide any nice input editing features such as interactive history, movement with cursor keys, tab completion, etc. (which makes it even more annoying), and then there's no input validation.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it's too interactive for your taste?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that you wrote a lot of questionable code that is only tangentially related to the question.

Comment: @melpomene: *"Parsing CSV with regexes is a very bad idea"* There is no international standard for CSV data, so every CSV document has to provide its own de facto standard. Just because there are CSV files somewhere in the world whose data contains newline characters doesn't mean that every program everywhere should support it. The vast majority of CSV data is handled correctly by `split /,/` and there is no reason to use anything more elaborate. Even `Text::CSV` doesn't support the very common practice of using a comma and a space to separate fields.